# Problem with python function to get news source- Requests Package

Tags: python, python-requests

I a created a function in python to get news from the source I am specifically requesting. However, when I run the function it brings all the sources instead the source I am requesting.

this is the code I have so far:

```py
import requests   
import json   

apiKey = "4f7c31f7d0084161bffec9b5d4f78e33"  
def getNews(source):    
    # news api
    url = "http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=4f7c31f7d0084161bffec9b5d4f78e33"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    # read the url articles requested
    urls = []
    for a in data["articles"]:
      urls.append(a["url"])

    return urls

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  results = getNews('the-wall-street-journal')
  print(results)
```

When I print the results instead of getting, the Wall Street journal I get news from all the sources.

Comment: Because people can exploit your API key for their needs, "4f7c31f7d008xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" like so.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually use the source in your query, and might as well pass the api key that way too.  Also I had to modify the source to get results.

```
import requests   
import json   

apiKey = "redacted!"  
def getNews(source, key):    
    # news api
    url = f"http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q={source}&country=us&category=business&apiKey={key}"
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.json()

    # read the url articles requested
    urls = []
    for a in data["articles"]:
      urls.append(a["url"])

    return urls

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  results = getNews('wall street journal', apiKey)
  print(results)
```

Output

```
['https://www.wsj.com/articles/bonds-were-a-safety-net-when-stocks-fell-investors-fret-they-arent-anymore-11601887725', 'https://www.wsj.com/articles/what-you-need-to-know-about-social-impact-investing-11601823600']
```